# TypeORM: "No migrations pending" when attempting to run migrations manually

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a new web app and I've written a migrator to create a user table. However, no matter what I try, typeorm does not appear to find this migrator and hence, does not run it.

My file structure (other files/folders not shown):

```
├── Server
│   ├── dist
|   |   ├── Migrations
|   |   |   ├── 1234567891234567890-AddUserTable.js
|   |   |   ├── 1234567891234567890-AddUserTable.js.map
|   |   |   ├── 1234567891234567890-AddUserTable.d.ts
│   ├── src
|   |   ├── Migrations
|   |   |   ├── 1234567891234567890-AddUserTable.ts
|   |   ├── app.module.ts
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({ envFilePath: '.env' }),
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                type: 'mysql',
                host: configService.get('TYPEORM_HOST'),
                port: +configService.get<number>('TYPEORM_PORT'),
                username: configService.get('TYPEORM_USERNAME'),
                password: configService.get('TYPEORM_PASSWORD'),
                database: configService.get('TYPEORM_DATABASE'),
                synchronize: configService.get('TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE'),
                entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
                migrations: [__dirname + '/Migrations/**/*.js'],
                migrationsRun: false,
                cli: {
                    migrationsDir: './Migrations',
                },
            }),
            inject: [ConfigService],
        }),
    ],
    controllers: [],
    providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private connection: Connection) {}
}
```

In order to run this, in my console window, I type: `nest start` in order get my Server started.

Then, I run `npx typeorm migration:run` which I get:

```
query: SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'myDB' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'migrations'
query: SELECT * FROM `myDB`.`migrations` `migrations` ORDER BY `id` DESC
No migrations are pending
```

If I look in my DB, I see a `migrations` table with no entries inside.

I have tried to delete my migrator file and create it again with a more recent timestamp and that does not work either.

```
npx typeorm migration:create -n "MyMigratorName"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try changing `cli: { migrationsDir: './Migrations' } ` to `cli: { migrationsDir: __dirname + './Migrations' } `

Comment: That did not work.

Comment: I am having the same issue

Answer (score 31):

For anyone coming here for help:

The config above mentions migrations to be found in js files:

`migrations: [__dirname + '/Migrations/**/*.js'],`

However from the folder structure its clear that migrations are written in ts files not js.

To run migrations from ts follow the officially recommended way described here:

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/using-cli.md#if-entities-files-are-in-typescript

Also in that case don't forget to update the migrations blob to be ts:

`migrations: [__dirname + '/Migrations/**/*.ts'],`

If you want to run the migrations from js files you will have to provide the location to be from dist folder after the ts files have been compiled to js form.

Comment: What does __dirname is supposed to mean? whenever i implement it, it gives me error, it appears with red color, or am i supposed to put something different in dirname's place? I'm confused, having a lot of problems with typeORM migrations );

Comment: I had the same problem and this fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Typeorm only loads migration from files with js extension,

In the ormconfig file where you set up your connection;

```
{
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "username": "test",
    "password": "test",
    "database": "test",
    "entities": ["entity/*.js"],
    "migrationsTableName": "custom_migration_table",
    "migrations": ["migration/*.js"],
    "cli": {
        "migrationsDir": "migration"
    }
}
```

`"migrations": ["migration/*.js"]` - indicates that typeorm will load migrations from the given "migration" directory.

if your migration folder is stored in a dist or src directory,

`"migrations": ["migration/*.js"]` will now be `"migrations": ["dist/migration/*.js"]` or
`"migrations": ["src/migration/*.js"]`, the * means any migration filename.
Just make sure whatever directory/directories placed here `["migration/*.js"]` leads to where your migration file(s) are

`"migrationsDir": "migration"`- indicates that the CLI must create new migrations in the "migration" directory. so whatever directory you specify here is where your migration files will be created.

Please note that if your migration files have typescript extensions(.ts), you have to compile your migrations files into javascript files if not typeorm will not find them.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. I tried almost every option available but typeorm just didnt work with typescript; giving one or the other errors. I finally built dist for migrations

Answer (score 3):

In addition to answer given by @Upka Uchechi

If you're using typescript, you need to run the following commands

```
$ npm run build   # This will compile the typescript files into JavaScript files 
$ npm run typeorm -- migration:run
```

To give a bit more context.
If your configuration files are lookated at `<PROJECT ROOT>/db-migrations`, the build command above should move the compiled JavaScript files to `<PROJECT ROOT>/dist/db-migrations`. For that, your configuration file would look like this

```
  ... 
  "migrations": ["dist/db-migrations/*.js"],
  ...
```

Comment: I feel like such an idiot for not anticipating this - thanks for your answer - this saved me!

Comment: Well, I also learned this by being stupid! We all learn by being stupid :D

Answer (score 1):

You **can** have your migrations in TS file, just run them using `typeorm-ts-node-commonjs` as stated in the [official documentation](https://typeorm.io/using-cli#if-entities-files-are-in-typescript)

For example, this is my data-source.ts:

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'db',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'postgres',
  database: 'test',
  logging: true,
  migrations: ['src/migrations/*.ts'],
});
```

And per the docs, I added the `typeorm` on my `package.json` scripts

```
"typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs"
```

So I can simply run them with

```bash
npm run typeorm migration:run -d src/data-source.ts
```

For ease of use, I suggest adding these scripts to your package.json

```json
  "scripts": {
    // ...
    "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs",
    "migration:show": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:show -d src/data-source.ts",
    "migration:run": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:run -d src/data-source.ts"
  },
```

So you can see the pending migrations as well as run them by calling

```bash
npm run migration:show
npm run migration:run
```

Comment: for me adding `"typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs"`in the scripts of package.json didn't enable me to use `npm run typeorm migration:show -d src/data-source.ts`. It always ignores the -d flag resulting in executing `npm run typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:show src/data-source.ts`. `npm run migration:show`works for me though. So i have to add all commands to the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Run typeorm in ts-node. You don't need to compile anything.

Answer (score 0):

It worked with me with resolve() as `migrations` directory is outside `src`

```
import { resolve } from 'path';

export const typeOrmOptions: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: ...,
  host: ...,
  port: ...,
  username: ...,
  password: ...,
  database: ..
  migrations: [resolve(__dirname, '../migrations/*.ts')],
};
```